# Redshift: Count of users who have 2 types of chats open with other users

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Following is a snippet of my data set:

[image]

- `_id` is the ID of the chat thread.
- `creatorid` is the ID of the user who created the chat thread.
- `partnerid` is the ID of the user who receives the chat message.
- `type` is the type of chat.

I am interested in finding the count of users who have 2 types `(either offer_related or request_related) and direct` of chats with another user.

I tried partitioning by `creatorid` and grouping by `partnerid` but that included other undesirable cases as well.

Does someone know a solution to this? I am using Amazon Redshift.

Chats which have the type 'offer_related' and 'request_related' are called work chats.

So, the objective is to find people who have 1 work chat and 1 direct chat open with the same person.

for example,

- User A has an offer_related chat with B
- user A has a direct chat with B
- User B has a direct chat with C
- user B has an offer_related chat with D.

So, only user A counts towards the answer since he has 1 work chat(offer_related) and 1 direct chat with the same user B.

Comment: Can you please edit your answer to show a sample of your desired output, given the sample input you have already shown?

Comment: Hello @JohnRotenstein. I edited the question to include an instance. I hope that clears the air a bit :) Thank you.

Comment: No, please add a **sample output** you would want from the query, given some of the rows from the screenshot you provided. This will allow us to recreate your data and try to devise a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get all the chats which are of the requested types, group by creator AND type - then keep only those which have more than 1 type of chats, and finally count the rows in the resultset:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 
  (SELECT creatorid FROM chats 
  WHERE type IN ('direct', 'offer_related', 'request_related') 
  GROUP BY creatorid, partnerid, type 
  HAVING COUNT(type) > 1) AS tmp
```

## UPDATE

Added `partnerid` in the grouping clause.

Comment: Hello. This query only counts people who have more than 1 type of chats. It doesn't, however, check if they are with the same user. I have mentioned an example in the question to better explain the issue.

Comment: Does it work if you add the `partnerid` in the grouping ?

Comment: :) Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM (SELECT creatorid, parnerid, COUNT(*) as num_chats
      FROM chats 
      WHERE type IN ('direct', 'offer_related', 'request_related') 
      GROUP BY creatorid, partnerid 
      HAVING MIN(type) <> MAX(type)  -- check that there is more than 1
     ) cp;
```